# Alignment issue with IE6

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-6, gridpanel

I was building a module in `gwt`. One of the functionality is that I will get multiple records in `GridPanel` from database. When I hover over on a particular record it should display some information like "click on the row to provide feedback". I have implemented it and it is working fine. But for IE when I hover over, it is displaying the message at top-left corner. Getting alignment problem.

Used this line in my code.

`grid.setToolTip("Click on the row to provide feedback");`

Comment: Show all the relevant the code you have so far.

Comment: @Tunaki I have only the above mentioned line for this purpose in my entire code. Rest of the code is irrelevant.

Comment: @AbhijithNagaraja ya it's a module for an organization. Testing guys will test in the respected browsers as per there conventions.